Why are ChronicleMap stable releases x.24 and x.25 not available on Maven Central?
I have a question regarding chroniclemap stable releases.
Reading the blog [1] seems that stable releases are regularly shipped to maven:
At any one time, it’s possible that we will support the current major release series and two older release series. At the time of writing, we have released x.26 early access but ship x.25 and x.24 stable release series regularly.

in Maven Central[2], I only see stable releases up to 3.23.5, whilst the above suggests that x.25 and x.24 should be available too?
Are stable x.25 releases available for open source offering or should I just re-set my expectations?
[1] https://chronicle.software/chronicle-25-whats-new-and-improved/
[2]https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.openhft/chronicle-map

The answer to my question is actually published at [1]
Only EA releases are released to Maven Central. Releases of stable versions (e.g. x.23) are made to Chronicle’s nexus and are available to customers with a commercial agreement.

[1] https://github.com/OpenHFT/OpenHFT/blob/aa79b18031dbecfd6722aa285a495e87e2d016d5/docs/Version-Support.adoc#ea-early-access
